# 553 5.0.0 Message-Id header line format error

Tags: smtp

I got this error from SMTP logs. Most mail goes through fine but a particular mail server is rejecting my mail due to invalid Message-Id format. It returns:

```
553 5.0.0 Message-Id header line format error
```

I have control over the application which is generating message IDs using this format:

```
C: Message-ID: e1cd55e5dd79ab5f6d6a9280dbbe60f7.1562596225153@speakingemail.appserver.co.nz
```

I can change this format to something else but I am not sure what to change. What could be wrong with this format?

Answer (score 0):

Just realised!

It needs angle brackets. Perhaps also should be lowercase D but the lack of angle brackets is the likely cause. Most mail servers don't mind but some do.

Should be:

```
C: Message-Id: <e1cd55e5dd79ab5f6d6a9280dbbe60f7.1562596225153@speakingemail.appserver.co.nz>
```